# Vscode: How to change javascript path style for auto imports in settings (importModuleSpecifier)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to add the setting for javascript , regarding "Preferred path style for auto imports.", available on the default settings on this page: [default settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings)

There is the setting: `"javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "shortest",`

So I wanted to add that and change the value to "non-relative".

I couldn't find anything when searching in the settings in vscode, and if I go into `settings.json` and add it manually like:

```
"javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "non-relative"
```

, it becomes greyed out and it says:

```
Unknown Configuration Setting
```

So where/how to change it?

**Update**: if I open the command palette (ctrl+shift+p) and search for `defaultSettings.json`, I can open that file. I see that there are no settings beginning with "javascript" nor "typescript" but there are such settings in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings).
But php is available, for example "php.validate.enable", so what happened with javascript/typescript, do I have to enable it in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the settings wasn't available in `defaultSettings.json` was that I'm using `Volar` with "take over mode". It is enabled by disabling `"TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features`" which provide those settings.

So it's more Volar related, I guess it is up to that plugin or whatever plugin is used in take over mode.